# size of an array of pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I'm writing a program that receives a text input from the user, and saves it in an array of pointers, each word as a pointer (let say in char** words)

My question is: once I have it, how would I know the size of words?

Comment: you have to loop through and sum up

Comment: Without code it's hard to tell what exactly is the problem.

Comment: ok I thought I had another choice...thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to look at a C array and tell how many elements it contains, so you'll need to keep track.

In fact, you likely need to keep track of 2 things: (1) how large the array you've created is (the maximum number of words you can handle), and (2) how many words you've actually seen so far.

Answer (score 1):

Count them while being read form the user.